# VC++ Unsigned long value changed to negative number what passing to oracle procedure

Tags: c++, oracle, c++11, unsigned

i'm using C++ Unsigned Long DWORD datatype to pass greater than 2147483647 to oracle procedure. but inserting negative number in procedure. not sure why.

Procedure parameter is defined as number.

same code working on 2003 window server.

but when using the code in 2012 window server and build in VS2005 32bit mode and deploy the dll i'm facing this issue.

is it related to Windows, Oracle or C++?

Comment: probably some abi misalignment, your column data type might be signed.

Answer (score 0):

When passing 32-bit parameters the C++ compiler doesn't care if a parameter is signed or unsigned, it just puts the 32-bits on the stack to pass them.  Where signed vs. unsigned matters is in comparisons done in code.

It sounds like you're passing in an unsigned value to a function that's expecting a signed value.  Your greater than 2147483647 unsigned value is then interpreted as the signed value the function was expecting meaning it's interpreted as a negative number. If the function you're calling is an Oracle procedure, then I would suspect that procedure is defined as accepting a signed value.